# Map on my android studio

Tags: java, android

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

how can i get/change another API for may map?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose you can create and use other account. But for end use you have to pay to google for there services.